# Split a dataframe in two and change variable name only of one of the two dataframe (setnames)

Tags: r, data-manipulation

my data looks something like this

```
df <- data.frame("Reporter" = c("A", "B", "C", "D","E","F"),
                 "Val" = runif(6, min=-1, max=1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
print(df)
  Reporter         Val
1        A -0.73660420
2        B -0.42937474
3        C  0.33622319
4        D -0.04887796
5        E  0.18333113
6        F  0.42065791
```

I would like to split the dataframe in two. Creating a new database where `Val` is changed to `Pos`. The problem in doing so, is that it also changes the name `Val` in my original df. While I would like it to remain the original `Val`.

```
pos <- df%>%filter(Val>0)%>%setnames("Val","Pos")
names(df) #It changes also the name of the original database df
[1] "Reporter" "Pos"
```

Is it possible to change only the name in Pos using `setnames`? What is the more intuitive and efficient alternative?

Comment: you are using `setnames` from `data.table` package which does an inplace replacement. Consider using `rename` or even `setNames` or even `set_names` functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `setNames`:

```r
df <- data.frame("Reporter" = c("A", "B", "C", "D","E","F"),
                 "Val" = runif(6, min=-1, max=1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


setNames(df[df$Val > 0,], c("Reporter", "Pos"))

#>   Reporter       Pos
#> 1        A 0.7660045
#> 2        B 0.2164235
#> 3        C 0.4912267
#> 5        E 0.4441980
#> 6        F 0.5605368
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single line in base R:

```r
pos <- `colnames<-`(df[df$Val > 0,], c("Reporter", "Pos"))
```

---

Here's a full reprex:

```r
df <- data.frame("Reporter" = c("A", "B", "C", "D","E","F"),
                 "Val" = runif(6, min=-1, max=1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

pos <- `colnames<-`(df[df$Val > 0,], c("Reporter", "Pos"))

df
#>   Reporter        Val
#> 1        A  0.5208991
#> 2        B -0.4968299
#> 3        C -0.4692309
#> 4        D  0.2960035
#> 5        E -0.1099399
#> 6        F  0.0360583

pos
#>   Reporter       Pos
#> 1        A 0.5208991
#> 4        D 0.2960035
#> 6        F 0.0360583
```